# Why did Lucy convert herself into a USB?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucy

What was the reason behind the conversion of human into USB in the movie *Lucy*?

Why did the heroine change herself into USB when she used 100% of her mind, and then texted the policeman ("I am everywhere")?

She traverses many old eras, and in the end just forms a strange structure, giving the researcher (scientist) USB and then that huge structure falls off?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lucy didn't turn herself into a USB stick.

She changed into a kind of 'super magic quantum computer' thing to convert her gained knowledge over time and space into a digital form current day scientists can use. USB stick is easily recognizable to the viewership as a data storage device, and why she didn't give a 'better' more scifi thing such as a tesseract.

After this, she disappears, entering a new plane of existence. Which also allowed her to text the police officer "I am everywhere"

She has become omnipotent, omniscient and omnipresent. IE, All powerful, all knowing, and all present.

The USB is full of information for humanity to use.

Comment: yh as she is the one there who used 100% cerebral network